# Multicast in EKS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-eks

AWS introduced VPC **multicast** support recently.

I deployed a pod with two containers to an EKS cluster which talk to each other using multicast. This config works.

When i put client and server in two **different** pods, hosted on **same node**, multicast does not work.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Thanks

Comment: Probably missing some information [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/tgw/working-with-multicast.html) like the multicast group.

Comment: @lloyd - i did setup multicast group and transit gateway - no dice.